# Uso della punteggiatura alla fine di affermazioni che hanno la medesima struttura sintattica delle domande

Tags: orthography

Supponendo si voglia scrivere la seguente frase

> È mai possibile che i media italiani non parlino del TTIP

per esprimere la convinzione che i media italiani dovrebbero parlarne diffusamente ma non lo fanno, con quale punteggiatura si dovrebbe chiudere, '.', '!?', '?' o '!'?

La prima impressione è che l'uso del '?' si attagli bene alla struttura della frase essendo la stessa, sotto il profilo sintattico, una domanda, ma, in realtà, per quanto innanzi spiegato, non lo è.

Comment: Il termine "[profilo] sintattico" qua è usato correttamente: la sintassi è l'insieme delle regole che controllano l'ordine delle parole e il relativo significato in tale ordine. Il testo si riferisce al fatto che la costruzione della frase denota che si tratta di una domanda, perciò sì, si tratta di sintassi.

Comment: Mi sono posto la domanda opposta leggendo David Copperfield in lingua originale, perché l'autore usava il punto interrogativo alla fine di frasi interrogative, anche quando costruite con una struttura di affermazione. Evidentemente in inglese questo tipo di casi è trattato diversamente da quanto non si faccia in italiano.

Comment: @FedericoBonelli: Infatti, l'uso della punteggiatura cambia da lingua a lingua. Quando si traduce, bisogna “tradurre” anche la punteggiatura.

Answer (score 5):

È una domanda, ancorché retorica, e quindi è giusto che abbia il punto interrogativo. Che una domanda sia retorica si deve capire dal contesto e dalla formulazione, non dalla punteggiatura.

Un eventuale punto esclamativo in più si potrebbe anche mettere, ma ritengo dia un'enfasi eccessiva e controproducente.